# Question about proof of rotation number of inverse map of circle homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

This question concerns a previous question, [Rotation number of inverse maps on the circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845851/rotation-number-of-inverse-maps-on-the-circle/1150202#1150202) in which all the terminology and notation used below is defined.

The question is given the rotation number $\rho (f)$, calculate the rotation number $\rho (f^{-1})$. All proofs I have found of this statement calculate $\rho(F \circ F^{-1})$ (for $F, F^{-1}$ lifts of $f, f^{-1}$) and end up with something like:

$\rho(F\circ G)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(F\circ G)^n(x)-x}{n}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{F^n(G^n(x))-G^n(x)}{n}+\dfrac{G^n(x)-x}{n}\right)=\rho(F)+\rho(G)$

For $F, G$ lifts of commuting circle homeomorphisms $f, g$, and the proof ends by letting $G = F^{-1}$. But in the definition of rotation number for $f$, i.e. $\rho(F) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{F^n(x)-x}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{F^n(x)}{n}$, if we let $x = F^{-n}(y)$ for some $y$ as above we get that the rotation number is $\rho(F) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{y}{n} = 0$ for any $f$ (note that the rotation number is always defined and has the same value for any $x$ in the domain of $F$).

So my question is are we allowed to use a function $G^n(x)$ in place of a variable $x$ in the definition of rotation number as the proofs commonly do, or are these proofs incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty confused. They are used as such in the definition. When you substitute $x = F^{n}(y)$, it changes to $y - F^{-n}y$. Since $f$ and $g$ commutes, their lifts too. Only that property is being exploited here.

Comment: I agree I'm confused, but what about when you use the equivalent definition of the rotation number without the $-x$ term in the numerator? The $F^n(x)$ and $x = F^{-n}(y)$ cancel each other out to get $y / n$ as $n \to \infty$ surely? The reason I ask is my course uses the definition $\rho(F) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{F^n(x)}{n}$, without a $-x$ in the numerator.

Comment: @D.P Let $f$ be the anticlockwise rotation of $\Bbb{S}^1$ with angle $2\pi \theta$. Then what do you think the rotation number is ?

Comment: $f(x) = x + 2\pi\theta \mod 1$, so lift $F(x) = x + 2\pi\theta$ and $F^n(x) = x+ 2n\pi\theta$ giving $\rho(F) = 2\pi\theta$, so $\rho(f) = 2\pi\theta \mod 1$.

Comment: If $f(z) = e^{2\pi i \theta }z$, then $F(x) = x + \theta$ will be lift and $F^n(x) = x + n\theta$. Then $\rho(f) = \theta \mod 1$. How is this possible by your definition?

Comment: $\dfrac{x}{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ so the definitions are equivalent. I'm still confused as to why we can substitute a variable $y$ dependent on $n$ into the definition of $\rho(F)$ when $y$ is evaluated inside a $\lim_{n\to\infty}$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write $x=F^{-n}(y)$ unless $F$ is invertible.

Comment: I'm confused, that's true but in this case $F$ is invertible; my problem is in the proof I linked have $F^{-n}(x)$ in the place of $x$ in the first fraction corresponding to $\rho(F)$. If $F$ is a lift of an invertible homeomorphism $f$ with none zero rotation number and we do the same thing and let $x = F^{-n}(y)$ in the definition $\rho(F) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{F^n(x)}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{y}{n} = 0$ which contradicts the fact $\rho(F)$ is non zero. What I mean is in the definition of $\rho(F)$, $x$ does not depend on $n$ but in the proof linked the chosen value of $x$ does.

Comment: In the proof they were using it for invertible $F$

Comment: I don't think the fact they use it for invertible $F$ makes my counterexample invalid, rather the counterexample relies on $F$ being invertible to get a rotation number of 0 for a function with non zero rotation number.

Comment: $F^n - I_{\Bbb{R}}$ is a period one function for every $n$ and it is bounded. This fact is used in proving that rotation number does not depend on the point. Can you show that the definition you are speaking is indepedent of the point?

Comment: Yes but it won't fit in the comment section here,  a source is page 102-103 of An introduction to chaotic dynamical systems by Robert L. Devaney or page 4 of these lecture notes http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/john_smillie/maths_4240/ma424_notes_2013.pdf . From looking at either proof I can't any relevance of this to my counterexample, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Ignore everything I have written on this comment section, I have finally realised that I am being dumb and the counterexample is wrong because $y = F^n(x)$ so $\dfrac{y}{n} \to \rho(F)$.